# How to set PropertyNamingStrategy for RestTemplate in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have written a SpringBoot app that consumes a rest api and presents a rest api.  My model pojo's have camelCase named properties.  The json that the app consumes has under_score property names.  The json that the app produces has under_score property names.  I would like to use a PropertyNamingStrategy that will do the conversion automatically between Java and json names during marshalling/unmarshalling.

I have Java config that attempts to set a naming strategy that can handle this;

```
/**
 * Configuration for Rest api.
 * <p>
 * Created by emurphy on 2/25/16.
 */
@Configuration
    public class RestConfig
    {
        /**
         * Bean to make jackson automatically convert from
         * camelCase (java) to under_scores (json) in property names
         *
         * @return ObjectMapper that maps from Java camelCase to json under_score names
         */
        @Bean
        public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper()
        {
            return new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(new UpperCaseUnderscoreStrategy());
        }

        /**
         * Property naming strategy that converts both ways between camelCase and under_score
         * property names.
         */
        public static class UpperCaseUnderscoreStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase
        {
            /**
             * Converts camelCase to under_score and
             * visa versa.  The idea is that this
             * name strategy can be used for both
             * marshalling and unmarshaling.
             *
             * For example, "userName" would be converted to
             * "user_name" and conversely "user_name" would
             * be converted to "userName".
             *
             * @param input formatted as camelCase or under_score string
             * @return input converted to opposite format
             */
            @Override
            public String translate(String input)
            {
                if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
                {
                    return input; // garbage in, garbage out
                }

                //
                // we always take the first character;
                // this preserves initial underscore
                //
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                final int length = input.length();
                int i = 0;  

                //
                // skip initial underscores
                //
                while ((i < length) && ('_' == input.charAt(i)))
                {
                    sb.append(input.charAt(i));
                    i += 1;
                }

                while (i < length)
                {
                    //
                    // find underscores, remove and capitalize next letter
                    //
                    while ((i < length) && ('_' != input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        sb.append(input.charAt(i));
                        i += 1;
                    }

                    if(i < length)
                    {
                        if('_' == input.charAt(i))
                        {
                            // underscore to uppercase

                            //
                            // skip underscores
                            //
                            while ((i < length) && ('_' == input.charAt(i)))
                            {
                                // skip underscores
                                i += 1;
                            }

                            //
                            // capitalize
                            //
                            if (i < length)
                            {
                                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else // uppercase to unscore + lowercase
                        {
                            sb.append('_');
                            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
                            i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
```

I can see the naming strategy's translate method getting called when my rest service converts Java pojos to json for the response.  However, when I'm consuming a rest api, via RestTemplate, I don't see this get called and my resulting pojos are not correctly intialized from the incoming json; all properties whose name would need translation are null.  This has forced me to use @JsonProperty on most properties.  I have a lot of properties and a lot of pojos - this is a very inelegant, boilerplate kind of solution that SpringBoot is supposed to help with.  Is there a way I can set a PropertyNamingStrategy that RestTemplate will use to convert the incoming json names from under_score to camelCase?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the annotations at the top of your config class?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've update the code in the question.  Basically  At Configuration.  My main configuration is in another file and has the At SpringBootApplication annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating a `RestTemplate` you need to set the `objectMapper` to yours. 
Also, you should declare your custom ObjectMapper as a `@Bean` so it is constructed by Spring as a singleton and managed for you. Do the same for the `PropertyNamingStrategy`, instead of 'newing' it up and declaring the class as static.

```
public class RestConfig
{
    /**
     * Bean to make jackson automatically convert from
     * camelCase (java) to under_scores (json) in property names
     *
     * @return ObjectMapper that maps from Java camelCase to json under_score names
     */
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper()
    {
        return new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(propertyNamingStrategy());
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyNamingStrategy propertyNamingStrategy()
    {
        return new UpperCaseUnderscoreStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
       jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(jacksonObjectMapper());
       messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
       restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters); 

       return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

And your class is in a separate file? It doesn't need to be static.

```
    /**
     * Property naming strategy that converts both ways between camelCase and under_score
     * property names.
     */
    public static class UpperCaseUnderscoreStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase
    {
        /**
         * Converts camelCase to under_score and
         * visa versa.  The idea is that this
         * name strategy can be used for both
         * marshalling and unmarshaling.
         *
         * For example, "userName" would be converted to
         * "user_name" and conversely "user_name" would
         * be converted to "userName".
         *
         * @param input formatted as camelCase or under_score string
         * @return input converted to opposite format
         */
        @Override
        public String translate(String input)
        {
            if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
            {
                return input; // garbage in, garbage out
            }

            //
            // we always take the first character;
            // this preserves initial underscore
            //
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            final int length = input.length();
            int i = 0;  

            //
            // skip initial underscores
            //
            while ((i < length) && ('_' == input.charAt(i)))
            {
                sb.append(input.charAt(i));
                i += 1;
            }

            while (i < length)
            {
                //
                // find underscores, remove and capitalize next letter
                //
                while ((i < length) && ('_' != input.charAt(i)) && !Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i)))
                {
                    sb.append(input.charAt(i));
                    i += 1;
                }

                if(i < length)
                {
                    if('_' == input.charAt(i))
                    {
                        // underscore to uppercase

                        //
                        // skip underscores
                        //
                        while ((i < length) && ('_' == input.charAt(i)))
                        {
                            // skip underscores
                            i += 1;
                        }

                        //
                        // capitalize
                        //
                        if (i < length)
                        {
                            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
                            i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else // uppercase to unscore + lowercase
                    {
                        sb.append('_');
                        sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
                        i += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've implemented this but it still does not work.  When I remove the @JsonProperty annotations in my pojos, I can still see that only properties with simple names, like 'description', get filled in when I make a rest call.  If I set a break point in the instance of UpperCaseUnderscoreStrategy.translate(), it never stops there so it is clear that the rest template is not calling it.

Comment: I can see when debugging that a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is chosen from the list of messageConverters.  I've traced further into the ObjectMapper and I can see that the DeserializationConfig returned by ObjectMapper.getDeserializationConfig() has it's _propertyNameStrategy value of null, so whatever we've done so far has not gotten into the deserialization pipeline.

Comment: Ok, I have figure this out.  Your answer was very helpful.  I found out that my low level code was new'ing up a RestTemplate on each call, so the configured template was ignored.  Once I changed to autowire the rest template into my low level, everything worked.  Now I see the translate() method being called as expected.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter answer is to use the Spring's objectMapper. The benefit is that it shares the same configuration in `application.properties`. So you can set `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` or whatever there, and it's consistent across the entire application including RestTemplate. Code as follows.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HTTPConfig {
    public final ObjectMapper objectMapper;  // provided by spring

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper))
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! using the objectMapper `new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this annotation above POJO's which u will be sending or receiving in ur request response.

> @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)

P.S. the strategy can be different depending upon the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this method. You can also add it as a spring bean.

```
private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE));
    messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    return restTemplate;
}
```