# Ignore JSON attribute cases declared with @JsonProperty with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, resttemplate

I use `@JsonProperty` to serialize data from a JSON through Spring `RestTemplate`'s `exchange`.

```
@JsonProperty("ip_address")
public String ipAddress;

@JsonProperty("port")
public Integer port;
```

I need this property to recognize both upper and lowercase versions of the attribute names i.e. "ip_address" and "IP_ADDRESS" set in `@JsonProperty` should be recognized.

I have tried the following and none worked:

- `@JsonFormat(with=JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)` applied on a class level does not work with [existing issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1886) reported in GitHub. Also does not work when applied to each attribute in the model class.
- [use `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` on an `ObjectMapper` bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547099/11159477).
- [This example using `ObjectMapper` and `RestTemplate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096162/11159477) also didn't work even with a combination code with the example on the item before.

All three just have `null` values for their respective attributes because I disabled error on unknown attributes (a.k.a. the different letter case) for the template.

Comment: Do you have an error when trying those solutions?

Comment: @AndrianekenaMoise I updated the question but they just have `null` values i.e. when I expected "ip_address" but "IP_ADDRESS" is in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working without changing my original pojo class @JsonProperty configs. Using the Object Mapper and Rest Template example you linked to but instead of a Property Naming strategy use the case insensitive mapper feature

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

Comment: Hi I am trying to get this working.  Where in the application startup did you create ObjectMapper?  I added in a static section, but it is never called.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell jackson to convert all your property names into e.g. SNAKE_CASE variants and set your `@JsonProperty` accordingly:

Example:

in spring boot set the property in application.properties

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

or you can enable it for just your single class and annotate the class with:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE.class)
```

and then set @JsonProperty:

```
@JsonProperty(vale="ip_address")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot App to Ignore Case for JSON attributes names:
Step 1: Make sure your POJO/Domain/Model class has a constructor with respective parameters, and remove any zero arg constructor.
Step 2: Add Jackson lib as a dependency
Ex:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 3: Enable in application.properties file as below
spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true