# @JsonProperty present but returning null

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I have an annotated `Java 11` class that's using `Fasterxml` and it's returning null for one of the properties even though I can see the data  in the source `JSON`. Is there a reason that this annotation no longer works with `jackson:2.12.0`?

The property in question is capitalized in the source so it's capitalized in the annotation as well.

**Source JSON**

```
{
    "stringOne": "hello",
    "stringTwo": "world",
    "floatOne": 0.0,
    "NUM": 15   <-- always returns null
}
```

**Log Statement**

```
TestJson{stringOne='hello', stringTwo='world', floatOne=0.0, NUM=null}
```

**Class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.io.Serializable;

@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
public class TestJson implements Serializable{

    protected String stringOne;
    protected String stringTwo;
    protected Float floatOne;
    protected Integer NUM;

    @JsonProperty("stringOne")
    public String getStringOne() {
        return stringOne;
    }

    public void setStringOne(String stringOne) {
        this.stringOne = stringOne;
    }

    @JsonProperty("stringTwo")
    public String getStringTwo() {
        return stringTwo;
    }

    public void setStringTwo(String stringTwo) {
        this.stringTwo = stringTwo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("floatOne")
    public Float getFloat() {
        return floatOne;
    }

    public void setFloat(Float floatOne) {
        this.floatOne = floatOne;
    }

//////// Returns null for every 'NUM' property
    @JsonProperty("NUM")
    public Integer getNum() {
        return NUM;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("NUM")
    public void setNum(Integer NUM) {
        this.NUM= NUM;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestJson{" +
                "stringOne='" + stringOne + '\'' +
                ", stringTwo='" + stringTwo + '\'' +
                ", floatOne=" + floatOne +
                ", NUM=" + NUM+
                '}';
    }
   
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding the request used to retrieve/serialize the data as a `TestJson` object

```
ClientResponse<TestJson> response = null;
TestJson testJson = null;
logger.info(encodeForLog("apiUrl.getPath: " + apiUrl.getPath()));
logger.info("proxy:" + proxy);

try {
    response = proxy.getData(apiUrl.getPath());

    if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        testJson = response.getEntity();
                
        return testJson;
    } else {
        throw new FailedException("HTTP failure");
    }
}
finally {
    if (response != null) {
        response.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096204/ignore-json-attribute-cases-declared-with-jsonproperty-with-spring-resttemplate

Comment: How do you do your deserialization? Just ran this test and it outputs `TestJson{stringOne='hello', stringTwo='world', floatOne=0.0, NUM=15}`

`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(str, TestJson.class));`

Comment: @UsmanAzhar the ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES annotation is currently present at the class level

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Migwel I've added the request code. The legacy code uses deprecated `ClientResponse<T>`

Comment: This is not a [mre]. If it is just a problem with Jackson, make a simple runnable main method with an ObjectMapper and test the serialization.

Answer (score -1):

Set @JsonProperty on setter method.

```
@JsonProperty("NUM")
public Integer getNum() {
    return num;
}

@JsonProperty("NUM")
public void setNum(Integer num) {
    this.num = num;
}
```

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a
> "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized, deserialized) as a logical property.
>
> https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

Jackson version doesn't matter:

> https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

Tested with this class (Jackson 2.11.4):

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
public class TestJson implements Serializable {

    protected String stringOne;
    protected String stringTwo;
    protected Float floatOne;
    protected Integer num;

    @JsonProperty("stringOne")
    public String getStringOne() {
        return stringOne;
    }

    public void setStringOne(String stringOne) {
        this.stringOne = stringOne;
    }

    @JsonProperty("stringTwo")
    public String getStringTwo() {
        return stringTwo;
    }

    public void setStringTwo(String stringTwo) {
        this.stringTwo = stringTwo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("floatOne")
    public Float getFloat() {
        return floatOne;
    }

    public void setFloat(Float floatOne) {
        this.floatOne = floatOne;
    }

    //////// Returns null for every 'NUM' property
    @JsonProperty("NUM")
    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    @JsonProperty("NUM")
    public void setNum(Integer num) {
        this.num= num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestJson{" +
                "stringOne='" + stringOne + '\'' +
                ", stringTwo='" + stringTwo + '\'' +
                ", floatOne=" + floatOne +
                ", NUM=" + num+
                '}';
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

and a better solution for TestJson:

```
public class TestJson implements Serializable {

    protected String stringOne;
    protected String stringTwo;
    protected Float floatOne;
    protected Integer num;

    @JsonCreator
    public TestJson(@JsonProperty("stringOne") String stringOne
            ,@JsonProperty("stringTwo") String stringTwo
            ,@JsonProperty("floatOne") Float floatOne
            ,@JsonProperty("NUM") Integer num) {
        this.stringOne = stringOne;
        this.stringTwo = stringTwo;
        this.floatOne = floatOne;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getStringOne() {
        return stringOne;
    }

    public void setStringOne(String stringOne) {
        this.stringOne = stringOne;
    }

    public String getStringTwo() {
        return stringTwo;
    }

    public void setStringTwo(String stringTwo) {
        this.stringTwo = stringTwo;
    }

    public Float getFloat() {
        return floatOne;
    }

    public void setFloat(Float floatOne) {
        this.floatOne = floatOne;
    }

    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(Integer num) {
        this.num= num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestJson{" +
                "stringOne='" + stringOne + '\'' +
                ", stringTwo='" + stringTwo + '\'' +
                ", floatOne=" + floatOne +
                ", NUM=" + num+
                '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the other fields fail as well if this were the case?

Comment: Because the field names match the json keys.

Comment: Check the fields name. if you change num field to NUM everything will be ok.

Comment: Perhaps,you have a problem in object mapping.Reference to @Migwel comment.